# What update will open my workbook to today's date?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like my workbook to open on the cell of today's date.  The dates of 2017 are listed in row 10.  My macro is listed below but contains a syntax error on the line
'x = Format(Date, "Short Date")'

```
Private Sub Workbook_OpenDate()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks("2017 Capacity Planner.xlsm")

    Worksheets("Dashboard").Select
    x = Format(Date, "Short Date")

    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets(“Dashboard”).Row(10).Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
    Application.Goto Selection, True

End Sub
```

Comment: what error? Typemismatch?

Comment: I'm not sure why I receive a syntax error?  The dates of 2017 are listed in row 10, I would like the macro to open the workbook and open to the cell of today's date.  I have tried several different macros without success.

Comment: ah, because of magic quotes.. see the updated code as edited by @ShaiRado. Use `"` instead of  `“`

Comment: Thank you, but now I am receiving a "runtime error9 - Subcript out of range".

Comment: You are using `Activate` before confirming `Find` has found something.  You are looking for the string x.  Are the values in row 10 strings?

Comment: Do not used `On Error Resume Next` like this.  It means don't bother me with errors.  It should only be used so:  `On Error Resume Next` `Statement that might fail for external reasons` `On Error Goto 0` `Check for errors`.

Comment: Did you mean to write `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("2017 Capacity Planner.xlsm")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are still using magic quotes. Even if you remove that you will Error 438 on the line .Row(10). Then on the find another error is waiting when nothing is found.Change your code like this :

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim x As String

    Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks("2017 Capacity Planner.xlsm")

    Worksheets("Dashboard").Select
    x = (Format(Date, "Short Date"))

    Set rng = Worksheets("Dashboard").Rows(10).Find(What:=x, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Parent.Activate
        rng.Select
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Why do u need to select the worksheet before the .Find ? Maybe add a MsgBox if the date is not found ?

Comment: agreed, didn't change that part just copied OP's code and made few changes but sure that part is redundant.

Comment: That works great after adding the .Open to the line Set wb.  Thank you all for your help.  Very much appreciated.